# Canon EOS Rebel t3i has developed weird settings seemingly over night?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, camera-settings

I've had this T3i for possibly 2 years now and it's worked fine fo this whole time, I took it out to film for the day, and the next day it was acting a little different.

Some of the main things I noticed were:

1. I can no longer access menus, gallery or live view in these shooting presets: A_DEP,M, AV, TV, P - it only shows this screen. [image: lcd while in these modes]
2. Along with not being able to access settings, I can only see my LCD screen in Video, all other modes (aside from modes in 1, will show the name and this screen.)[image: screen 1, before pressing display] Until I press the display button, then it shows my live screen, but also mentions that it's not available in 'this mode', except it's in every mode. [image: screen 2 after pressing display]

Here's what I've tried to fix with:

- Resetting to factory (didn't help)
- Setting "LCD off/on BTN" to "Remains On"(All this did was allow me to see these screens in the modes from '1', if I don't have this selected, than my LCD remains black.
- Running the sensor cleaning (no noticeable change).

It will still take pictures and save them to gallery, but I have almost 0 control over my LCD screen in multiple modes.

Does anyone here have any idea what could of happened, or how to fix this? I am 100% positive that dirt/water/debris didn't get into the machine, it's never been dropped or banged around, any ideas?

---

Edits:
Here is what a snapshot from a recording looks like:
[image: snapshot of recording]

Comment: When you are in Tv, Av, or M mode what happens when you press the *Info* button?

Comment: @MichaelClark the screen stays the same in all of those modes (where they show your settings).

Comment: Even when you press the *Info* button? If that is the case your camera need to be checked out by a service center (or you need to consider replacing it since fixing it could very well cost more than it is worth).

Comment: What happens when you try to record a movie?

Comment: When on video, I can pull up menu and Info, and even record. I did notice though that if I take a snapshot, I have 2 gray bars sitting on the image, i'll edit a pic of them into my question

Comment: Does your camera have a 16:9 crop mode when taking stills in movie mode? That's what the blue bars look like.

Comment: @MichaelClark, yup fixed that, but that unfortunately is not the main issue at hand haha

Comment: I think you are missing what @MichaelClark is trying to say. The screen that your camera is stuck on is the **Info** screen. When that screen appears, the **Info button** should remove it.

Comment: @IsaacWasserman Yeah, nothing is happening though, i've been looking around online for the past couple hours as well. It seems to be a recurring problem with people, I think my motherboard or firmware may be fried.

Comment: Firmware doesn't just go bad. You would've needed to update your firmware for it to change at all. If your motherboard was bad, the issue would present itself in much more severe ways than the info screen being on perpetually. I think it's more likely that your Info button is broken which is likely to be an easy repair for a professional.

Comment: @IsaacWasserman My info button works in other modes though, that's why it seems to be a motherboard thing. All of those buttons, Live View, Menu, Info, DISP, all work in non creative modes.

Comment: @IsaacWasserman That's not the Info screen, that is the "Quick Control" Screen.

Comment: After reading the other comments, it seems to me as if your camera has a button stuck (and _always_ pressed).

Comment: @Roflo, I don't think because every button works in every other (Non-creative) mode. But once I hop into a creative mode, such as A_DEP,M, AV, TV or P, all functions from the Menu, Info, control pad go out the window.

Comment: Any luck here? I have been experiencing the same thing. Curious about the stuck button thing, but all seem to function properly.

Comment: @JasonOstrander I just sort of wrote the camera off, I chatted with a local camera place and they said if I've gone through all this, at this point it would have been cheaper to buy a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing another firmware, like [Magic Lantern](https://builds.magiclantern.fm/), see if anything changes. If it doesn't work, you can always install the [official firmware](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/cameras/support-dslr/eos-rebel-t3i-body?subtab=downloads-firmware).
The only caveat is that it might void your warranty.

Comment: I believe I tried this, but wasn't able to get to the set up menu. I would say my warranty is long past voided so I'm not worried about that. I'll try it again sometime later tonight